# Arabic charecter is not showing in HTML

Tags: html, css, encoding, arabic

I'm using HTML and trying to display a content in Arabic ( جميع الحقوق محفوظة ) but it's coming as unkown characters Ø±ÙØ¨ÙÙ.

1- i have used (  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` ) in `<head>`

2- i have added this ( `dir="rtl"` ) in `<p>` tag

please check below my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="bottom">
            <p dir="rtl">جميع الحقوق محفوظة</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which browser on which os you are having issues, i tried in both `firefox-71.6` and `chrome-79.0.39` on macOS and it was displaying properly for me.

Comment: i'm using Windows 10 and Chrome